# The moment problem for $m_n=1/n$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, moments

What is the p.d.f. for the moments $m_n=1/n$ ?

(They are obtained from $\int_0^1 x^n/x\ dx $, but clearly $1/x$ is not a p.d.f. on $[0,1]$)

Comment: $-\log x\ge 0$ on $0<x<1$ and $\int_0^1 (-\log x)\, dx =1$, so this works just fine as a density.

Comment: @ChristianRemling thanks! Indeed. I've now changed a bit of my question.

Comment: the variance $m_2-m_1^2=-1/2$ is negative for $m_n=1/n$, so these moments are not allowed [and please don't edit your post by deleting a question and asking a new one, to avoid that comments you receive no longer make sense]

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Ok, thanks.  Then what if I consider the moments say $m_n=1/(10n)$ so the variance is positive.